# How to change the Auto Growth size? MS SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

In MS Sql server 2005, by default 1MB Auto Growth is there, How can i change it to whatever i need.?

Thanx,
Ambanna

Answer (score 13):

In SQL Server Management Studio, right click on the database.
Go to Properties.
Then go to the Files section.
Click on either the data or log autogrowth column (Click the ...)
Then change it to whatever you want it to be.

Comment: Thanks. +1. Management Studio usability sucks big time.

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the size to handle your data needs for the next few months. You do not want to depend on auto grow as a habit. You'll fill up your disk, and you delay performance of the server while files grow.